# An open source schedule system

Tags: open-source, calendar, scheduling

I'm looking for an open source system that will manage employee shifts.

The software has to have features that make the distribution fair, allowing to make customize rules, and must have a UI.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.Especially, you need to list your requirements explicitly (including the OS the software should run on). Your current specifications are much too broad (e.g. what makes the distribution "fair"?).

Answer (score 3):

Look at ShiftExec Pro, its Lite version is free and open source:

http://www.shiftexec.com/

It's enough well written, that it should be very easy to implement any missing features.